# Asp Core 2 Deploy to Azure not found my dbcontext

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I want to deploy my project, but my database context not found. is there any setting that can make it can be found?
[image]

Comment: What type of DbContext are you using? Is it in a separate project or inside the ASP.NET Core app? Are you using EF Core?

Comment: yes i am using EF Core

Comment: What is the exact error/exception that you get and when do you get it? Can you post more details about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following documentation to configure a DbContext.

[Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext).

[This](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Visual-Studio-Publish-Integration) other article may be useful to understand how is the DbContext used on EF6 and EF7.